# Python FBX SDK – How to scale models that have keyframes?

Tags: python, maya, fbx, mel

I am trying to script with Python FBX SDK to scale models. And I am using `LclScaling.Set()` to set scale value. But I found if this model has keyframes, then the scaling is not applied.

So my question is how to properly scale models that have keyframes. Here is my code:

```
scale = node.LclScaling.Get()
value = 0.5
node.LclScaling.Set(fbx.FbxDouble3(scale[0] * value, scale[1] * value, scale[2] * value))
```

Comment: I figured it out. In Maya, if I set translate or rotate keyframes, the scale property would also has Animation Node in FBX SDK. So, if I want to modify scale property, I should use SetChannelValue or FbxAnimCurveFilterScale instead of LclScaling.Set()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you can't scale your model that already has animation keyframes, it seems that it has keyframes on a `Scale` parameter, even if scale is not changing during playback session. That could be possible in situation when user animates just a position of a model pressing <kbd>S</kbd> shortcut. This shortcut generates 10 keyframes at a time, but only `translation`/`rotation` keyframes are important for you here.

[image]

***Solution***:

Delete redundant keyframes in Graph Editor manually or programmatically.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

cmds.cutKey('pSphere1', time=(1,100), attribute='scaleX', option="keys")
cmds.cutKey('pSphere1', time=(1,100), attribute='scaleY', option="keys")
cmds.cutKey('pSphere1', time=(1,100), attribute='scaleZ', option="keys")
```

After this you can easily scale your model.

## P.S.

The other appropriate way is to update old scale keyframes for FBX model (first in the beginning and second in the end of animation).

Comment: Thanks! It is really helpful! I eliminate some problems by your method, but I still get that problem. For example, the model has rotation keyframes and I ensure there are not scale keyframes, then it's scale value still cannot be changed by my script. Maybe I can add scale keyframes for those models to fix that problem. And are there any differences between mesh and skeleton? Thanks again!

Comment: I believe that character's mesh has to be managed by skeleton. So all keyframes must be assigned to skeleton (except deformer's keyframes).

Comment: BTW, do you know how to enable autocomplete for Python FBX SDK in editor?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. In Maya, if I set translate or rotate keyframes, the scale property would also has Animation Node in FBX SDK. So, if I want to modify scale property, I should use `SetChannelValue` or `FbxAnimCurveFilterScale` instead of `LclScaling.Set()`